# Script always runs two instances

Tags: shell, shell-script, process

I was just curious, what may be the reason why script run two instances when executed.

Whenever I run my script `foo.sh`, and when I check using:

```
$ ps -ef | grep foo.sh
```

It always returns two instances.

```
user 30643 28793  0 11:09 pts/4    00:00:00 /bin/sh /foo.sh
user 30645 30643  0 11:09 pts/4    00:00:04 /bin/sh /foo.sh
```

#### foo.sh

Here's the contents of the script.

```
#!/bin/sh 

string="<IPADDRESS>" 
string2="<HOSTNAME>" 
string3="|" 
_date=$(date +"%D") 
_time=$(date +"%T") 


tail -n 0 -F /tmp/snmp_debug.log | \ 
while read LINE 
do 
echo $LINE | grep -q $string 
if [ $? = 0 ] 
then 
hostAdd=$(echo $LINE | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2;}') 
echo "HostIP: $hostAdd" >> sqlInsert.log 
fi 

echo $LINE | grep -q $string2 
if [ $? = 0 ] 
then 
echo "$_date $_time" >> sqlInsert.log 
hostName=$(echo $LINE | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $4}') 
echo "Hostname: $hostName" >> sqlInsert.log 
fi 

echo $LINE | grep -q $string3 
if [ $? = 0 ] 
then 
#output number of delimiters 
pipeNo=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '|' '{print NF-1}') 

#CCN Alarms 
if [ $pipeNo == 8 ] 
then 
echo $pipeNo >> sqlInsert.log 
errorTrim=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '[|-]' '{print $7}') 
echo $errorTrim >> sqlInsert.log 

#map CCN severity 
sevLev=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '|' '{print $7}') 
if [ $sevLev == 1 ] 
then 
sevLev=1; 
elif [ "$sevLev" -ge 2 ] && [ "$sevLev" -lt 6 ] 
then 
sevLev=10; 
elif [ $sevLev == 6 ] 
then 
sevLev=5; 
fi 
echo "Sev $sevLev" >> sqlInsert.log 

probCause_t=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '|' '{print $6}') 
probCause=$(grep -E "^$probCause_t" CCNProbCause.lookup | awk -F '|' '{ print $2 }') 
echo "ProbCause $probCause" >> sqlInsert.log 
alarmRem1=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '|' '{print $3 $8 $9}') 
alarmRem2=$(echo $alarmRem1 | sed "s/\"//g;s/\://g") 
alarmRem="$probCause $alarmRem2" 
echo "Rem $alarmRem" >> sqlInsert.log 
C_type=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '|' '{print $5}') 
echo "C-type $C_type" >> sqlInsert.log 
alarmType=$(grep -E "^$C_type" EricssonEventsCCN.lookup | awk -F '|' '{ print $2 }') 
echo "Type $alarmType" >> sqlInsert.log 


##Connect and insert to DB >> CCN 
sqlplus -s UPM_USER/UPM_USER << EOF >> sqlInsert.log 
insert into alarmlog_06 (errorid,agentid,moduleid,moduleinstance,hostaddress,severity,remarks,status,entrydate,umuidate,classid) VALUES ($errorTrim,28,6034,1,'$hostAdd',$sevLev,'$alarmRem','P',sysdate,sysdate,$alarmType); 
commit; 
exit; 
EOF 

#echo "Done Inserting to DB" >> sqlInsert.log 
echo "======================================" >> sqlInsert.log 

#SDP & AIR Alarms 
elif [ $pipeNo == 5 ] 
then 
echo "Pipe: $pipeNo" >> sqlInsert.log 
probCause_t=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '|' '{print $5}') 
probCause=$(grep -E "^$probCause_t" SDPAIRProbCause.lookup | awk -F '|' '{ print $2 }') 
echo "ProbCause $probCause" >> sqlInsert.log 
alarmRem1=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '|' '{print $3}') 
alarmRem2=$(echo $alarmRem1 | sed "s/\"//g;s/\://g;s/\;//g") 
#alarmRem="$alarmRem2 $probCause" 
alarmRem="$alarmRem2" 
echo "Rem $alarmRem" >> sqlInsert.log 
SA_type=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '|' '{print $4}') 
alarmEType=$(grep -E "^$SA_type" EricssonEventsSDP.lookup | awk -F '|' '{ print $2 }') 
echo "EventType $alarmEType" >> sqlInsert.log 
alarmModesc=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '[|-]' '{print $7}') 
echo "AlarmModelDesc $alarmModesc" >> sqlInsert.log 
moduleid=$(grep "$alarmModesc" EricssonLookup.lookup | awk -F '|' '{ print $4 }') 
echo "MOduleID $moduleid" >> sqlInsert.log 

#map Severity for SDP & AIR 
sev1=$(echo $LINE | awk -F '|' '{print $6}') 
echo "Severity $alarmSev" >> sqlInsert.log 
if [ -z "$sev1" ] 
then 
sev=$(grep "$alarmModesc" EricssonLookup.lookup | awk -F '|' '{ print $3 }') 
if [ -z "$sev" ] 
then 
sev=10; #default severity for sdp&air (10) error 
else 
#map returned severity value 
if [ $sev == 1 ] 
then 
sev=1; 
elif [ "$sev" -ge 2 ] && [ "$sev" -lt 6 ] 
then 
sev=10; 
elif [ $sev == 6 ] 
then 
sev=5; 
fi 
fi 
echo "Severity $sev" >> sqlInsert.log 
else 
sev=$sev1 
fi 

errornum=$(grep "$alarmModesc" EricssonLookup.lookup | awk -F '|' '{ print $2 }') 
if [ -z "$errornum" ] 
then 
errornum= 
insertstring="insert into alarmlog_06 (agentid,moduleinstance,hostaddress,severity,remarks,status,entrydate,umuidate,classid) VALUES (28,1,'$hostAdd',$sev,'$alarmRem','P',sysdate,sysdate,$alarmEType);" 
echo "ErrorID Not Found" >> sqlInsert.log 
else 
insertstring="insert into alarmlog_06 (errorid,agentid,moduleid,moduleinstance,hostaddress,severity,remarks,status,entrydate,umuidate,classid) VALUES ($errornum,28,$moduleid,1,'$hostAdd',$sev,'$alarmRem','P',sysdate,sysdate,$alarmEType);" 
echo "ErrorID $errornum" >> sqlInsert.log 
fi 

##Connect and insert to DB 
sqlplus -s UPM_USER/UPM_USER << EOF >> sqlInsert.log 
$insertstring 
commit; 
exit; 
EOF 
echo "========================================" >> sqlInsert.log 
fi 
fi 
done
```

Comment: Just hazarding a guess here, but do any of the script's commands end with a '&'?

Comment: No. None of the commands in the script has '&'

Comment: I left a comment to you in chat, can you please provide the contents of this `foo.sh`, otherwise we cannot assist you further, and I'll be forced to vote your Q closed as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

As slm, *finally* reached in his last comment, it depends on what `foo.sh` is actually doing. And you've not provided any part of this shell script.

For example, the following simple script will net the same result:

```
#!/bin/bash

( true; sleep 10 ) &
wait
```

Gives:

```
# /tmp/foo.sh &
[1] 14663
# pgrep foo.sh
14663
14670
```

(note: `bash` is smart enough to not run a sub-shell for a single, simple command, thus the `true`.)

**UPDATE**

Looking at the script you've now post, this is the expected behavior.  Your script requires two processes.  One is the main stream of commands (i.e. the one running `tail`), and the second is the sub-shell running the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The string you're grepping for is being returned as a match as well.

#### Example

Say I run this fake process called `sleep 100`.

```
$ sleep 100 &
```

I now check `ps` looking for processes named `sleep`.

```
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
sam      31473 31256  0 22:22 pts/6    00:00:00 sleep 100
sam      31476 31256  0 22:22 pts/6    00:00:00 grep sleep
```

The old school way of getting rid of this, is to make use of a trick and tell `grep` to search for a string using a regular expression (regex).

```
$ ps -ef | grep "[s]leep"
sam      31485 31256  0 22:24 pts/6    00:00:00 sleep 100
```

This makes use of the fact that `grep` is literally looking for whatever you tell it to find, in this case "[s]leep" but that doesn't match. The string `[s]leep` as a regular expression is equivalent to the string "sleep". The notation `[..]` is a set, in this case it contains 1 item, the letter `s`.

#### Modern method

A more modern method is to make use of the command `pgrep`. This command is designed to return information about processes by their name, however it's designed to omit matches that include `pgrep`.

```
$ pgrep sleep
31494

-or-

$ pgrep -l sleep
31494 sleep
```

#### But it's not a duplicate from grep

In your updated question you listed the output of `ps` like so:

```
user 30643 28793  0 11:09 pts/4    00:00:00 /bin/sh /foo.sh
user 30645 30643  0 11:09 pts/4    00:00:04 /bin/sh /foo.sh
```

This would seem to indicate that you have in fact 2 separate processes. I would kill the both of them and then restart it. You can use this command to kill both of them:

```
$ pkill -f /foo.sh
```

Comment: i used pgrep, but it still outputs two instances. I believe the two instances are both valid. How can i prevent two instances from running?

Comment: @user60216 - how are you starting them/it? BTW, I wrote the upper portion of my A prior to you updating the Q.

Comment: using this: ./foo.sh &
and then again, two instances will run..

Comment: when I kill both of them, and then restart using the command i said above, it will return two instances again.

Comment: @user60216 - I'm confused, you're running the script 2 times, so what's actually wrong? `./foo.sh &` runs the script backgrounded, running this 2 times runs it twice.

Comment: Sorry, I'm also confused. Is my using '&' sign makes it really run twice? (newbie here. lol!) If that is so, how will I be able to run the script and not end it when i press ctrl-c to continue some other task?

Comment: @user60216 - when you put a `&` at the end of a command it get's thrown to the background. This means it isn't tying up your command prompt. If you run it again, it runs 2x, again, it's running 3x. The `&` isn't making it run 2x's though. You are when you run ./foo.sh again. Using a `&` is the correct method for leaving a script running instead of Ctrl + C.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13360/discussion-between-user60216-and-slm)

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour.

Here if you will look at PPID (Parent Process IDs), second shell's PPID which is 30643 is same as first shell's PID. So it means first shell has called another shell.